# Angular 2 and webpack: unexpected closing tag "a"

Tags: angular, webpack

I have this Angular 2 template which display tabs of my Web site:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul id="tabs">
        <li *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let i = index" [class.active]="selectedTab===i">
            <a routerLink="/private/home/{{i}}">{{tab}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="tabContent">
    <span *ngIf="selectedTab==0"><welcome></welcome></span>
    <span *ngIf="selectedTab==1"><boiler></boiler></span>
</div>
```

It works perfectly well. Then, I try to use Webpack with default option to create unique *.js file: it still works.
Finally, in Webpack, I active the option to minimize the .js file and I get this error:

```
Unexpected closing tag "a" (" of tabs; let i = index" [class.active]="selectedTab===i">
<a routerlink=/private/home/{{i}}>{{tab}}[ERROR ->]</a> </li> </ul> </div>                 
<div class=tabContent> <span *ngif="selectedTab==0"><welcome></welcome></span")
```

Any idea on this error ?

Here the related code generated by Webpack:

```
function(t,e){t.exports='<div id=menu> <ul id=tabs> <li *ngfor="let tab of tabs; 
let i = index" [class.active]="selectedTab===i"> 
<a routerlink=/private/home/{{i}}>{{tab}}</a> </li> </ul> </div> <div class=tabContent> 
<span *ngif="selectedTab==0"><welcome></welcome></span> <span *ngif="selectedTab==1">
<boiler></boiler></span> </div>'}
```

Comment: A couple of things: are you using the `angular-cli`? Also, I'm surprised this works. `routerLink` should be a bound property and accepts an [array of values](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#link-parameters-array) representing a path, so it should look like `< a [routerLink]="['/private', 'home', i]"></a>`. And lastly, is there a reason you're using `*ngIf` to render a component instead of `<router-outlet>`? Router outlet is the more correct way to do this but I'm interested in knowing if there's a specific case that requires it to be this way.

Answer (score 5):

I guess the issue is with the `htmlLoader`. Depending on your webpack version you should set the `minimize` option to false in your webpack configuration.

**webpack 1** (inside the root of your configuration)

```
htmlLoader: {
    minimize: false
},
```

**webpack 2**

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
        options : {
            htmlLoader : {
                minimize : false
            }
        }
    })

]
```

Answer (score 1):

/private/home/{{i}} -> this is not in "".

try this for routerLink

```
<a [routerLink]="['/private/home/',i]">{{tab}}</a>
```

Comment: Thanks. It works but now I have a lot of errors in others files. Seems that webpack doesn't well handle correctly Angular 2 syntax when template file is not inline in .ts files.

Comment: i work with angular 2.2.x version and angular-cli and i have the template files in different location and looks fine. If you have any issue let us help you.